# NodeJS Joi Validation: Require either two fields or a third one

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

I want to allow API callers to enter geodata either via a [Geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) or via normal [geo coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system). My Joi Validation schema currently looks like this:

```
const schema = Joi.object({

        geoHash: Joi.string(),
        lat: Joi.number().precision(8),
        lon: Joi.number().precision(8),
    });
```

So how do I require either the geohash or lat and lon combined? How do I find out after the validation, which of these two options was used?

Answer (score 0):

Schema validation to require either the geoHash or lat + lon combined:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    geoHash: Joi.string(),
    lat: Joi.number().precision(8),
    lon: Joi
        .number()
        .precision(8)
        .when('lat', {
            not: undefined,
            then: Joi.required(),
        })
}).or('geoHash', 'lat');
```

I am not sure whether we can find which of the validation is used. I looked around the documentation and I couldn't find any.

You can have a simple Js code:

```
const isGeoHashUsed = !!req.query.geoHash // assuming it's a GET request
```

if true, then geoHash is used. Else, lat + lon is used.